# How to add a loop to my excel vba code to copy data from a set of workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code to copy data into one masterworkbook that works totally fine. But it only copies data from one workbook, which also has to be open.
Since I have a growing amoount of workbooks I would like to change the code so that

1. only the masterworkbook needs to be opened
2. data from all workbooks in one folder (or the worbooks can be selected with a message box) is copied not only from one specific workbook

My Code fdor now has noo Loop because i have no clue how to do this. Please help me. I cant sleep without having a solution :(

```
    Sub Copy_Paste_Below_Last_Cell()
'Find the last used row in both sheets and copy and paste data below existing data.

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

  Set wsCopy = Workbooks("New.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Set wsDest = Workbooks("Master.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
  '1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column A
  lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
  '2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column A
  'Offset property moves down 1 row
  lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

  '3. Copy & Paste Data
  wsCopy.Range("A2:T" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
    wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Should look something like this:

```vb
Sub Copy_Paste_Below_Last_Cell()

    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet, f
    
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'use ThisWorkbook (where the macro is running)
    
    'files are in a folder "Input Files" in the same folder as the "Master" workbook
    f = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Input Files\*.xlsx") 'get the first file
    Do While Len(f) > 0
        With Workbooks.Open(f, ReadOnly:=True)
            Set wsCopy = .Worksheets("Sheet1") 'source sheet
            
            wsCopy.Range("A2:T" & ws.Copy.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Copy _
               wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            
            .Close False 'no save
        End With
        f = Dir() 'next file (if any)
    Loop
  
End Sub
```

You can adjust the location of the folder being scanned to suit you needs, or have the user choose a folder.